# How to identify safari's "flash plugin" and get its pid

Tags: flash, scripting, safari, pid

I've got 64bit safari running a flash video (OSX snow leopard). I try to list all process using the ps command in a shell window. Flash for safari comes up as "Plugin Process" However, if there are other plugins running, they all seem to get taged as "Plugin Process". Is there a way to uniquely identify the flash plugin? Activity Monitor magically tags it as "Flash Player (Safari Internet Plug-in)" I want the same kind of behaviour from something I can control (ps, carbon, cocoa etc).

Background: I'm actually doing this programmatically using sysctrl and have the same problems as using ps.

Comment: alright, so in part to answer my own question. Once i have the pids of all "PluginProcess" items, I can loop through them and get bundle information using "ProcessInformationCopyDictionary". Here I can search for flash specific tags. Painful, but it'll prob work. I'll post code in once i get it cleaned up.

Comment: Actually, scratch that ... the dictionary doesn't seem to contain anything actually related to the plugin. Its all webkit plugin process related. :(

Comment: Can you tell how to do that